# How to access a class in CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to access at class `<div>` with class `.mine` and **make it's `background: blue`**. 
How can I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Meet Mome&#771;nto.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 my_menu">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- for collapsible button making -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
            <!-- for making icon bar -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- in order to collapse we will wrap ul in to div tag-->
        <div class="mine">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Slider</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Pages</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Shortcut</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container .row .my_menu .navbar-default .mine{
    background:blue;    
}
```

Comment: The reason you don't se blue background is that your `.mine` div has 0 height (that's because `.navbar-nav` is floated). Your selector is good, but in order to see the changes you have to target something with width and height dimensions (for example `.navbar-nav` div). You should learn basics of HTML and CSS first. There is a lot of resources on the web.

Comment: thanks maksh for your guidance but i do not get it i have heard that whenever you wrap any content inside div then div will automatically adjust its height according to its contents in this case .mine class is wrapping ul elements so it should adjust height its according to contents if not than why it is floating i have not used float property ? plz guide me

Comment: You are using Bootstrap which has its own CSS. You use `.pull-right` which is a Bootstrap class and it applies to that div `float: right`. When you are wrapping that floated div with your `mine` div it has 0 height because float is not cleared (you can read more here https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-2). If you are learning HTML/CSS I recommend you to not use Bootstrap and create your website from scratch. You will learn more with that approach, then if you know the basics, you can jump and use Bootstrap as your CSS framework.

Comment: oh thanks now i understand it i have forgotten i have already used pull-right property thanks brother. i will follow your instructions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twitter bootstrap maybe your css can overlap in this case use important!

```
.container, .menu, .row { background: blue important! };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your div with class mine has no height. It's contents are flowing out of it

Add this to your CSS:

```
.mine{
    background:blue;
    *zoom: 1;
}
.mine:before,.mine:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.mine:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

And your page will become like this:

```css
.mine{
    background:blue;
    *zoom: 1;
}
.mine:before,.mine:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.mine:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Meet Mome&#771;nto.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 my_menu">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- for collapsible button making -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
            <!-- for making icon bar -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- in order to collapse we will wrap ul in to div tag-->
        <div class="mine">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Slider</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Pages</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Shortcut</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```